# Why use SDL_Surface over SDL_Texture

Tags: sdl, image-rendering

I understand that SDL_Textures are rendered by the GPU, whilst SDL_Surfaces are rendered by the CPU. However, I don't understand why SDL_Surfaces would be used at all, given that SDL_Textures are apparently faster than SDL_Surfaces.

If possible, can anyone explain reasons why SDL_Surfaces are better than SDL_Textures (if any) or provide situations where SDL_Surfaces are better than SDL_Textures (if any)?

Comment: Taken directly from the [IMG_LoadTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2_image/IMG_LoadTexture) wiki page. “… can be significantly more efficient than using a CPU-bound SDL_Surface if you don't need to manipulate the image directly after loading it.”

Comment: @SafelyFast I apologise, but does that mean that if you need to manipulate the image directly, it can be faster?

Comment: What that means is if you don’t plan on manipulating the image then you’re better off using an `SDL_Texture`. If, however, you need to modify the image at runtime it is more efficient to use an `SDL_Surface`. However, you will almost always convert the surface into a texture at some point.